# Can TeX Live pretest be upgraded to official edition?

Tags: texlive

If I install a pretest version of TeX Live, can it be upgraded to the final release with `tlmgr` when that is out? Or will I have to install again?

Comment: It will be better to say "Can TeX Live 2011 beta be upgraded to the final edition?" Because I think pretest/beta is also officially developed by TeX Live team. :-)

Comment: You can update the pretest version by tlmgr. Unfortunately I don't know the release date.

Comment: No one knows the release date until the actual release :-) Anyway, it's very likely that the current tlpretest will be the released version.

Comment: Since you have some responses to your questions that seem to answer those, please consider marking some of them (one answer per question) as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the respective answer (and also to you!).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sure you can. The only thing you'll have to change is the repository URL: during the pretest phase, it's one of the repos here: http://tug.org/texlive/mirmon/ but after release it will be the usual CTAN mirrors. After release, you can change the default mirror with `tlmgr option repository <url>` or simply `tlmgr option repository ctan` if you want a CTAN mirror to be chosen automatically depending on your location.

Answer (score 7):

You only have to switch to another mirror if 2011 will be announced, 
only a few ones host the pretest.

```
tlmgr --repository=<TL2011 mirror> --self --all update
```